# Scheme Make list of all pair permutations of elements in two equal length lists

Tags: recursion, scheme, nested-loops, mit-scheme

I am trying to combine two lists of x coordinates and y coordinates into pairs in scheme, and I am close, but can't get a list of pairs returned.
The following can match up all the pairs using nested loops, but I'm not sure the best way to out put them, right now I am just displaying them to console.

```
(define X (list 1 2 3 4 5))
(define Y (list 6 7 8 9 10))
(define (map2d X Y)
    (do ((a  0 (+ a 1)))               ; Count a upwards from 0
        ((= a (length X) ) )           ; Stop when a = length of list
      (do ((b 0 (+ b 1)))              ; Count b upwards from 0
          ((= b (length Y) ) )         ; Stop when  b = length of second list
          (display (cons (list-ref X a) (list-ref Y b))) (newline)
        ))
)
(map2d X Y)
```

I am looking to have this function output

```
((1 . 6) (1 . 7) (1 . 8) ... (2 . 6) (2 . 7) ... (5 . 10))
```

I will then use map to feed this list into another function that takes pairs.

Bonus points if you can help me make this more recursive (do isn't 'pure' functional, right?), this is my first time using functional programming and the recursion has not been easy to grasp. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly speaking you're asking for the cartesian product of the two lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions of Óscar López are correct and elegant, and address you to the “right” way of programming in a functional language. However, since you are starting to study recursion, I will propose a simple recursive solution, without high-level functions:

```
(define (prepend-to-all value y)
  (if (null? y)
      '()
      (cons (cons value (car y)) (prepend-to-all value (cdr y)))))

(define (map2d x y)
  (if (null? x)
      '()
      (append (prepend-to-all (car x) y) (map2d (cdr x) y))))
```

The function `map2d` recurs on the first list: if it is empty, then the cartesian product will be empty; otherwise, it will collect all the pairs obtained by prepending the first element of `x` to all the elements of `y`, with all the pairs obtained by applying itself to the rest of `x` and all the elements of `y`.

The function `prepend-to-all`, will produce all the pairs built from a single value, `value` and all the elements of the list `y`. It recurs on the second parameter, the list. When `y` is empty the result is the empty list of pairs, otherwise, it builds a pair with `value` and the first element of `y`, and “conses” it on the result of prepending `value` to all the remaining elements of `y`.

When you will master the recursion, you can pass to the next step, by learning tail-recursion, in which the call to the function is not contained in some other “building” form, but is the first one of the recursive call. Such form has the advantage that the compiler can transform it into a (much) more efficient iterative program. Here is an example of this technique applied to your problem:

```
(define (map2d x y)
  (define (prepend-to-all value y pairs)
    (if (null? y)
        pairs
        (prepend-to-all value (cdr y) (cons (cons value (car y)) pairs)))) 
  (define (cross-product x y all-pairs)
    (if (null? x)
        (reverse all-pairs)
        (cross-product (cdr x) y (prepend-to-all (car x) y all-pairs))))
  (cross-product x y '()))
```

The key idea is to define an helper function with a new parameter that “accumulates” the result while it is built. This “accumulator”, which is initialized with () in the call of the helper function, will be returned as result in the terminal case of the recursion. In this case the situation is more complex since there are two functions, but you can study the new version of `prepend-to-all` to see how this works. Note that, to return all the pairs in the natural order, at the end of the `cross-product` function the result is reversed. If you do not need this order, you can omit the `reverse` to make the function more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Using `do` isn't very idiomatic. You can try nesting `map`s instead, this is more in the spirit of Scheme - using built-in higher-order procedures is the way to go!

```
; this is required to flatten the list
(define (flatmap proc seq)
  (fold-right append '() (map proc seq)))

(define (map2d X Y)
  (flatmap
   (lambda (i)
     (map (lambda (j)
            (cons i j))
          Y))
   X))
```

It's a shame you're not using Racket, this would have been nicer:

```
(define (map2d X Y)
  (for*/list ([i X] [j Y])
    (cons i j)))
```

Comment: @aeolus try using foldr, alternatively you can import it from srfi-1 or even implement it yourself, it's super-easy . I argue that the above is the most idiomatic solution, using existing procedures. Implementing everything from scratch is ok for learning, but not the way in real life.